# Html accessibility - read another element's description

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover, screen-readers

Hello any accessibility gurus,

I want to have this `button` element, when tabbed on, would trigger the screen read of an `input` element instead.

I tried pointing the `aria-labelledby` from the `button` to the `input`, to have the `input`'s `aria-label` being read out. But the `button` still reads out its own description, when tabbed on.

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="radio" id="inputid" aria-label="read me">
    <button aria-labelledby="inputid">don't read me</button>
</fieldset>
```

Is there a way to read another element's content?

Thank you,

---

2022-12-06 Edit:
Following Andy's comment, the `input` element is only visually hidden, so it was moved offscreen with css `left: -10000px`.

Comment: I’m sorry but I don’t understand. Could you try to be more clear of what you’re trying to achieve? Messing around with labels for elements with different roles sounds terribly confusing. Is the input hidden from assistive technology or only visually. So it still would receive focus before the button? What would clicking the button do? Beware of [WCAG 2.5.3 Label in Name](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/label-in-name.html) as well!

Comment: @Andy Maybe I made it sound more complex than it is. Basically, when I tap onto one element, I want the screen reader to read out the description of ANOTHER element instead.

Comment: Well it’s pretty clear what your question is, and `aria-labelledby` should be the way to go. But I’m concerned about the implications this might have for users of assistive technology.

Comment: I agree with @Andy that what you're trying to do could be (will be) very confusing. However, your code snippet works fine when I tried NVDA, JAWS, and Voiceover (iOS).  It said "read me, button". I didn't hear "don't read me".  What screen reader did you test with?

Comment: @slugolicious I am using Voiceover on MacOS. I find that only the initial input I focused on after form submission works by reading the `aria-labelledby`. If I have several inputs, the latter ones won't be read when I tab onto them.

Comment: Could you try and provide an interactive code example? You didn’t answer to my question of how the input is hidden. You mention _initial input_,, does that refer to the `<input>`? It can be focussed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `aria-labelledby` is not used according to the standards, which might explain undefined behaviour.

The [Accessible Name and Description, step C](https://w3c.github.io/accname/#step2C) mentions the following:

> If the embedded control has role textbox, return its value.

That means that if an `<input>`, which has implicit role `textbox`, is used as part of an accessible name, not its label, but **its value is used as the name**.

Further, the ARIA standard on `aria-labelledby` reads:

> If the interface is such that it is not possible to have a visible label on the screen, authors SHOULD use `aria-label` […]

The main purpose of `aria-labelleby` is to refer to part of the visible contents of an element like a `<form>` to label it. Most commonly, this would be a heading like `<h2>`.

---

The use case of this question is currently unclear to me. The example provided does not make sense with a single `radio` input.

- If the `<input>` is completely hidden, visually and from assistive technology, why is it there in the first place? `<input type="hidden">` would be the more correct input to use if the form data is needed
- If it’s only hidden visually, both the button and the input can be focussed, which is terribly confusing. Does the input appear on screen once it receives focus?